# SQL Server cursor to vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, cursor

everyone, How can I read a cursor from a stored procedure?

This is my code, but it's not working

```
 Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conexionBD").ToString())
 Public Function LoadData() As String

     Dim strQuery As String
     strQuery = "Kardex_P''"

     Using (con)
        Dim sqlComm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)

        con.Open()

        Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()

        If sqlReader.HasRows Then
            While (sqlReader.Read())
                txtReporte = sqlReader.ToString
            End While
        End If

    End Using

    Return txtReporte
End Function
```

Please I need your help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stop wasting your time on making reading from the cursor work - instead, focus on **eliminating** the cursor altogether! In 95% of the cases, you **don't need** a cursor, really!  And you shouldn't use one, either - unless you absolutely have to.....

Comment: What marc_s said x 10,000 while changing the 95% to 98.99% :)

Comment: What is not working in the code above to make you think that a cursor would solve?

Answer (score 0):

The cursor code will live in the stored procedure that ultimately returns a set of rows to read. Reference each column by ordinal value or name:

```
txtReporte.Text = sqlReader(0).ToString()
```

or

```
txtReporte.Text = sqlReader("YourColumnName").ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong in OP code and how to fix it.

```
 Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conexionBD").ConnectionString
''//.ToString()) wrong but not fatal
 Public Function LoadData() As String
     Dim txtReporte as String = "" ''//you return this so declare

     Dim strQuery As String
     strQuery = "Kardex_P" ''//"Kardex_P''" This supposed to be SP name. What '' do inside?

     Using (con) ''//this is good
        Dim sqlComm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery, con)
        ''//By default command type is text so next line is critical
        sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        con.Open()

        Dim sqlReader As SqlDataReader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader()

        ''//If sqlReader.HasRows Then checking "HasRows is redundant here
            While (sqlReader.Read())
                ''//txtReporte = sqlReader.ToString no comment
              txtReporte &= sqlReader("SomeField")
            End While
        ''//End If
       con.Close() ''//cleanup recommended
    End Using

    Return txtReporte
End Function
```

I hope this will work. Not perfect of course.